# Redirect page with condition from routing file in Angular 5

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

1. I want to redirect page from my `app-routing.module.ts` file
2. I have two domain **i) abcd.in ii) abcd.hk**, so i want to redirect in different page from both Domain
3. Below is my routing file code

   ```
   {
       path: 'login',
       loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule',
       canActivate: [GuestGuard],
   },
   {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: './main-page/main-page.module#MainPageModule',
       canActivate: [GuestGuard],
   }
   ```

> I want to redirect on **login** path when my domain is **abcd.hk** otherwise on **second path**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it while checking the

```
location.hostname
```

In app.component.ts by taking in router in the constructor

If the

```
if( location.hostname == "abcd.hk")
   this.router.navigate(['/login]);
    else{
         this.router.navigate(['']);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
    '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    @Injectable()
    export class GuestGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private auth: AuthService,
        private myRoute: Router){
      }
      canActivate(
            next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        this.myRoute.parent.url.subscribe(urlPath => {
          this.url = urlPath[urlPath.length - 1].path;
        });
      }

   if(this.url === 'abcd.hk'){
        this.myRoute.navigate(['/login]);
         return true;
        } else{
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: it is possible without authguard?

Comment: you can use a guard for that.